# How can a Windows Phone 7 application register for push service updates when the phone starts?

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I have a WP7 app and want it to register for push notifications when the phone starts up?

Image I have some kind of messaging app, and don't want to force the user to click the tile to sign in and register for push notifications.

Are there any events that happen on startup that would give me access to my application?

I'm extremely lazy, and if I had a WP7 phone I wouldn't want to have to click on a ton of tiles just to log in if I have saved my credentials in isolated storage and had the ability to 'sign in when the phone starts'.

Answer (score 1):

Your user will need to run your application at least once, so you can fire your code off to register the push notifications channel with your server.

With that done, your server can push updates down to the device whether it's running or not.

Answer (score -1):

There is no such event available.

Your code cannot run in the background so even if you could react to such an event your ap couldn't run unless the user specifically started it.

You should instead look to use Tile or Toast notifications to communicate with the user when your application isn't running.